# How can i see if a tab within an HTML page exists and if so link to it to scrape data?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have some code (thanks to another user) which opens IE goes to a website and scrapes the data and feeds it back in to my sheet. The code works exactly how it should but i have a slight problem with it.

The code is as follows

```
'VBE > Tools > References:'1: Microsoft HTML Object library  2: Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub GetSoccerStats()
Dim ie As Object, t As Date
Dim objDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument, text As String
Dim lastRow As Long, dataSheet As Worksheet, inputArray(), i As Long


Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10


Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AVG GOAL DATA")
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With dataSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With


inputArray = dataSheet.Range("C4:E" & lastRow).Value
inputArray = GetLinks(inputArray)


Dim results(), r As Long, c As Long
ReDim results(1 To UBound(inputArray, 1), 1 To 8)


With ie
    .Visible = True
    For i = LBound(inputArray, 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1)
        r = r + 1
        .navigate2 inputArray(i, 4)


        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend


        Dim objTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable, objTableRow As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow


        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set objTable = .document.getElementsByClassName("table-main leaguestats")(0)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While objTable Is Nothing


        If Not objTable Is Nothing Then
            c = 1
            For Each objTableRow In objTable.Rows
                text = objTableRow.Cells(0).innerText
                Select Case text
                Case "Matches played", "Matches remaining", "Home goals", "Away goals"
                    results(r, c) = objTableRow.Cells(1).innerText
                    results(r, c + 1) = objTableRow.Cells(2).innerText
                    c = c + 2
                End Select
            Next objTableRow
        End If
    Next
    .Quit
End With
dataSheet.Range("F4").Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End Sub

Public Function GetLinks(ByRef inputArray As Variant) As Variant
Dim i As Long
ReDim Preserve inputArray(1 To UBound(inputArray, 1), 1 To UBound(inputArray, 2) + 1)


For i = LBound(inputArray, 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1)
    inputArray(i, 4) = IIf(inputArray(i, 1) = "CURRENT", inputArray(i, 2), inputArray(i, 3))
Next
GetLinks = inputArray
End Function
```

So, I have a worksheet that has a list of Football Leagues (in the rows), then columns hold the data. This code fetches data from betexplorer.com and populates this sheet (each row contains data corresponding to a league)

At the moment this code looks on my sheet to see that if in column C, the word is CURRENT, then use the URL provided in column D. If column C contains the word LAST it takes the URL from column E.

The problem is that Some leagues towards the end of the season get split in to groups (See https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/belgium/jupiler-league/stats/) As you notice when you land on this page it defaults you to giving stats to the 'Championship group' However there is a tab to the left that says 'main'. This is the data i need on the main tab. The further problem is that not all leagues have this. As far as i can tell, the 'main' stats tab has a different URL within an HREF tag so perhaps the VBA can use the link i provide on the worksheet, check to see if a 'main' tab exists, if it does not then just pull the data from that page, or if it does then redirect to the URL for the 'main' tab and pull the data from that one...

The HTML looks like this:

```
<li class="list-tabs__item"><a href="?stage=z3r4t5sS" class="list-tabs__item__in">Main</a></li>
<li class="list-tabs__item"><a href="?stage=hrVVyPkq" class="list-tabs__item__in current">Championship Group</a></li>
<li class="list-tabs__item"><a href="?stage=EPykCdW0" class="list-tabs__item__in">Europa League Group</a></li>
```

Comment: Can you share several urls where this is the case please?

Comment: https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/australia/a-league/stats/ https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/austria/tipico-bundesliga/stats/

Comment: I've given a few ways to try below.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to web lage through standard import external data master of Excel? It is very pretty sees tables on web pages and allows to insert them directly to sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of possible ways to go about this. You are testing for differences between the pages that are consistent. For example,  there are double rows of tabs for pages where the Championship occurs. There is stats tab row above and Championship tab row below. The id (if consistent across Championship tab pages) `sm-0-0` is only present in Championship tab pages and not in the normal pages. Also, you may only find class `list-tabs--secondary`  where there is the championship secondary row

Here are a few possibilities:

If the `href` had a consistent string, that uniquely identifies the Championship tab, you could test for the presence of that

```
If ie.document.querySelectorAll("[href*='stage=hrVVyPkq']").length > 0 Then
    'Championship tab is present 
Else
   'Championship tab is not present 
End If
```

---

Alternatively, you could test the length of default tabs on the page by class. If you have Championship tab as default (as well as the Stats parent/supra tab)  then you get a length of 2. If you have a length of 1 it is just normal.

```
If ie.document.querySelectorAll(".list-tabs__item__in.current").length > 1 Then
    'championship tab present
Else
    'Championship tab is not present 
End If
```

---

Testing for id (if consistently the same across championship pages)

```
If ie.document.querySelectorAll("#sm-0-0").length > 0 Then
'championship tab present
'switch to main
    ie.document.querySelector("#sm-0-0 a").click 'or >
    ie.document.querySelector(".list-tabs--secondary a").click
Else
    'Championship tab is not present 
End If
```

---

Testing for secondary tab row class

```
If ie.document.querySelectorAll(".list-tabs--secondary").length > 0 Then
'championship tab present
'switch to main
    ie.document.querySelector("#sm-0-0 a").click 'or >
    ie.document.querySelector(".list-tabs--secondary a").click
Else
    'Championship tab is not present 
End If
```

---

**Example implementation:**

```
Option Explicit

'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub GetImageLinks()
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, i As Long, links(), objTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable, t As Date
    links = Array("https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/austria/tipico-bundesliga/stats/", "https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/belgium/jupiler-league/stats/")
    'the first above has championship tab
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        For i = LBound(links) To UBound(links)
            .Navigate2 links(i)

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            If .document.querySelectorAll(".list-tabs--secondary").Length > 0 Then
                'championship tab present
                'switch to main
                .document.querySelector(".list-tabs--secondary a").Click

                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Else                                 'you don't need this part
                'Championship tab is not present
            End If

            t = Timer
            Do
                DoEvents
                On Error Resume Next
                Set objTable = .document.getElementsByClassName("table-main leaguestats")(0)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While objTable Is Nothing
            Debug.Print objTable.NamespaceURI
            Set objTable = Nothing
        Next
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: From what i can tell the only consistent is class="list-tabs__item__in">Main</a></li>

Comment: If id is not consistent then use bottom example and the second method for switching to main tab within that example

Comment: in fact the main difference is on a page where there are no tabs, the sm-0-0 id does not exist

Comment: Can you share that url? Does the bottom example not work?

Comment: Seems fine. That is what I classify as normal page. 1 row of tabs and no Championship tab.

Comment: OK. So id need to implement that to the GetSoccerStats Sub? I tried adding it just before the Do DoEvents and it redirects fine, i then get a run time error. It must be me as i am not 100% sure where to put the code

Comment: You want it after: While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend  but you may need an additional wait before it.

Comment: Where i put it i get a run time error 70 Permission Denied on this line : text = objTableRow.Cells(0).innerText. If i put it where you suggest i get a run time error 91 Object variable or with block variable not defined. on on the same line

Comment: I've added an example with one with/without

Comment: Thanks, i have tried implementing it to the Sub GetSoccerStats that you created, i still get a run time error. I must be missing a trick (or simply the knowledge). Thanks for all your help btw ;)

Comment: I can see two oversights (and they are my fault)  - I have gone back and corrected. Your current script should be something like:  https://pastebin.com/1Ram4xzZ

Comment: Ok great, that seems to work... except.... i get a run time 70 permission denied on this line : results(r, c + 1) = objTableRow.Cells(2).innerText. Whats weird is that it doesn't happen on the same league each time, sometimes i will get past 5 or 6 leagues and sometimes it will go through 20 and fail... Is it a timing thing?

Comment: Or could it be that there are some pages that have tabs, but they actually load on the main tab....so changing tabs would not work because its already on the correct tab...

Comment: Try changing Set objTable = Nothing  to  Set objTable = Nothing:  Set objTableRow = Nothing

Comment: Changing that this time i got a 91 error on this line : results(r, c) = objTableRow.Cells(1).innerText

Comment: currently running at a second time... and i got the run time 70 on objTableRow.Cells(0).innerText

Comment: it was also not on the same league.

Comment: It seems as if the page dosnt load quickly i get the error

Comment: Yeah.... you see where I say in the code additional wait may be required?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192651/discussion-between-user3672422-and-qharr).